# TinyMCE4 - could not set toolbar at the bottom of the editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In TinyMCE 3, we could set the toolbar at the bottom of the editor with:

`theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom"`.

I can't find how to do this with TinyMCE 4.

Comment: @Shqiptar_Programmer: do you really think that "Position of toolbar is a great title" ?

Comment: Adjusted the title as oldest one "Position of toolbar" could be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The advanced theme was removed in TinyMCE 4. If you want to set up the toolbar in the bottom part of the editor you must create your own skin or stick with your TinyMCE 3.x .

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x under removed themes